# How proccessor handles uninitalized variables?

Tags: c++, assembly

So I have assignment in which I basically have to figure out in assembly how the variables are stored and I have problem with figuring out how C++ handles various variables.

```
MyClass var;
MyClass *p = new MyClass();
var.setX(3)
```

What I think I figured out is:
*p refference is being stored on stack while the created object is being allocated on heap. 
Which would mean that p is refferencing the created object. Please confirm if correct.

The question is what happens with var, is it dynamically allocated?
I am looking through assembly but can't find anything that would point me to an answer.

Comment: Yes, `var` is likely allocated from the stack together with all the locals with just a single adjustment of the stack pointer. If it has no constructor that sets members to known values, that's all you will see.

Comment: In C++ terminology, the term *free store* refers to the *heap*, but the standard gives latitude to compiler vendors and platforms (e.g., embedded systems) that it may actually refer to something different from the heap.

Comment: Yes, `p` variable has the same storage considerations as `var`.  "On the stack" is a useful mental model, but the optimizer tries hard to not use the stack when it can use processor registers for the storage.  Makes the code faster.  Stack frames get allocated dynamically at function entry, you normally see a stack pointer adjustment early in the function disassembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saying that `p` is stored on the stack is misleading.  `p` has automatic storage duration, and will be stored wherever the compiler decides to store it, if the compiler decides to store it anywhere at all.  It *may* be stored on the stack, or maybe it lives entirely in a register and never ends up in memory at all.

`var` is exactly the same.  Since you call a method on it it's likely that space for it gets reserved on the stack, since most calling conventions require method calls to be passed the address of the object.  But maybe not.  If the full definition of `setX` is visible at the point of the call, maybe the compiler inlines the call.  It will all depend on the exact specifics of the program.  Here's [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/Z3Y7RQ) where the compiler does exactly that.  Notice that no part of `var` is ever written to memory at all; it's stored entirely in `esi`.

Similarly, the object allocated by `new` has dynamic storage duration.  That likely means that it will live in memory allocated from the system's heap, but that is, again, not specified by the C++ language.